# Queria dividir uma lista em duas partes

Tags: lista, lisp, autolisp

Eu queria dividir uma lista em duas partes conforme a tamanho digitado pelo usuário.
Exemplo:

```
(split 3 '(1 3 5 7 9))
```

Saída:

```
((1 3 5) (7 9))
```

---

```
(defun dividir (count lista
         (values (subseq count 0 lista) (subseq count lista)))
```

Comment: A pergunta está bem feita, é lisp a sintaxe é um pouco estranha mesmo. The Nightm4re, mais tarde dou olhada com atenção.